# Python - Accesing a list from another class method

Tags: python, class, methods, static

I have a little problem with two different classes and two methods from the same class. I have a class B which is using both methods from class a which seems to work fine. 
The problem however is that the first method from class a (insert) changes a list which the second method (lookup) from this class  should use. It is using the global list which is still initiated with only zeroes. So I have no idea how to tell the method to use the HashMap from the insert method :/ I Hope somebody can help, thank you!

```
""" PUBLIC MEMBERS

Insert the given key (given as a string) with the given value (given as 
an integer). If the hash table already contains an entry for the given key, 
update the value of this entry with the given value.
"""

class Map:
    global m 
    m = 10000
    global HashMap 
    HashMap = []
    for i in range(m):
        HashMap.append(0)

    @classmethod
    def insert(self, key, value):

        """
        >>> Map.insert("hi", 9)
        [4,53]
        """
        self.key = key
        self.value = value


        asci = 0  
        for i in key:
            asci += ord(i)
        hashindex = (asci%m)*2
        print(hashindex)
        print(HashMap[hashindex])

        if HashMap[hashindex] == key:
           HashMap[hashindex + 1] = value 

        else:
            while HashMap[hashindex] != 0:
                hashindex = ((asci+1)%m)*2  


            HashMap[hashindex] = key
            HashMap[hashindex+1] = value



    """ Check if there exists an entry with the given key in the hash table. 
   If such an entry exists, return its associated integer value. 
   Otherwise return -1.
    """

    @classmethod
    def lookup(self, key):

        self.key = key
        ascilookup = 0
        for i in key:
            ascilookup += ord(i)

        indexlookup = (ascilookup%m)*2


        for j in HashMap:
            if HashMap[j]==key:
                return HashMap[j + 1]

            elif HashMap[j]==0:
                return "-1"

            else:
                j =((j+1)%m)*2        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Why are you using a list to replace a hashmap? Use a [dictionary](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a far simpler implementation of a map in python:

```
class Map:
    HashMap = {}

    def __init__(self,leng):
        for i in range(leng):
            self.HashMap[str(i)]=0

    def insert(self, key, value):
        self.HashMap[key]=value


    def lookup(self, key):
        for each in self.HashMap.iterkeys():
            if each == key:
                return self.HashMap[each]
        return None
```

*EDIT* without using a dictionary, using two lists is easier:

```
class Map:
    keys = []
    values = []

    def __init__(self,leng):
        for i in range(leng):
            self.keys.append(str(i))
            self.values.append(0)

    @classmethod
    def insert(self, key, value):
        self.keys.append(key)
        self.values.append(value)

    @classmethod
    def lookup(self, key):
        for x in range(0, len(self.keys)):
            if self.keys[x] == key:
                return self.values[x]
        return None
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is, I'm not allowed to use the internal dictionary :/

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it. Maybe use 2 lists?

Comment: I've added a second solution without using a dictionary